How to update data based on select options in a React component?
I am encountering a problem in my code where I am creating a calculator which calculates the electricity consumption by appliances and suggesting them that which capacity of solar system will work for them. So the issue is I aim to map wattages onto my React component. However, I am unsure how to achieve this. I have attempted various methods, but I am only able to map using a specific index number (By hard coating the index number). What I desire is for the mapping to automatically update when a user switches the option.

Here is the code which I have written...
The part where I am mapping the wattages
{Object.entries(summary).map(([applianceName, quantity]) => (
                <p key={applianceName} className="text-sm">
                  {quantity *
                    appliances.appliances.find((a) => a.name === applianceName)
                      .options[0].wattage}
                  w
                </p>
              ))}

And here is the select and input part
 <select
          name={`${applianceName}-type`}
          id={applianceName}
          className="p-1 border-2 border-gray-400 rounded-md ml-2 text-xs"
          onChange={handleQuantityChange}
        >
          <option value="select">Please Select {applianceName} Type</option>
          {applianceTypes.map((type) => (
            <option key={type} value={type}>
              {type}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder={`Enter ${applianceName} Quantity`}
          min={0}
          className="p-1 border-2 border-gray-400 rounded-md ml-2 text-xs"
          onChange={handleQuantityChange}
        />

And just for the reference here is the Json data
"appliances": [
    {
      "name": "Fan",
      "options": [
        { "option": "AC (110w)", "wattage": 110 },
        { "option": "DC (55w)", "wattage": 55 },
        { "option": "Inverter (30w)", "wattage": 30 }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Tube Light",
      "options": [
        { "option": "18w", "wattage": 18 },
        { "option": "24w", "wattage": 24 },
        { "option": "36w", "wattage": 36 }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Led Bulb",
      "options": [
        { "option": "5w", "wattage": 5 },
        { "option": "7w", "wattage": 7 },
        { "option": "12w", "wattage": 12 },
        { "option": "15w", "wattage": 15 },
        { "option": "18w", "wattage": 18 }
      ]
    }
    ]

Now I'm not getting that how can I proceed

It looks like you're trying to calculate the total wattage for each appliance based on the selected type and quantity. You can achieve this by updating your mapping logic to use the selected type's wattage instead of hardcoding the index number. Here's how you can do it:
First, add state to your component to store the selected type and quantity for each appliance:
const [selectedTypes, setSelectedTypes] = useState({});
const [quantities, setQuantities] = useState({});

Then, update your handleQuantityChange function to update the selected type and quantity for the corresponding appliance:
const handleQuantityChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  const [applianceName, typeOrQuantity] = name.split("-");

  if (typeOrQuantity === "type") {
    setSelectedTypes({ ...selectedTypes, [applianceName]: value });
  } else {
    setQuantities({ ...quantities, [applianceName]: value });
  }
};

Finally, update your mapping logic to use the selected type's wattage:
{Object.entries(summary).map(([applianceName, quantity]) => {
  const selectedType = selectedTypes[applianceName];
  const wattage = appliances.appliances
    .find((a) => a.name === applianceName)
    .options.find((o) => o.option === selectedType)?.wattage || 0;

  return (
    <p key={applianceName} className="text-sm">
      {quantity * wattage}w
    </p>
  );
})}

With these changes, the wattage calculation will update automatically based on the selected type for each appliance. Make sure to also handle cases where a type is not selected or the selected type is not found in the options array.
